# make method generic for different viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have a method which accepts one viewmodel. i have to replicate same method for different viewmodel. i tried something like functionname (t model) but it didnt work.I am new to generics.
Can some one help me

```
       private void SetUpUserTypeDropDown(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        var usertypes = GetuserTypes();
        model.UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem> { };
        usertypes.ForEach(t => model.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Value }));
    }


     private void SetUpUserforBackOfficeTypeDropDown(BackOfficeViewModel model)
    {
        var usertypes = GetuserTypes();
        model.UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem> { };
        usertypes.ForEach(t => model.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Value }));
    }
      private void SetUpProfileTypeDropDown(MyProfileViewModel model)
    {
        var usertypes = GetuserTypes();
        model.UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem> { };
        usertypes.ForEach(t => model.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Value }));
    }
```

I am forced to copy paste same code with different method names. Can i get some help in this regard how to make a generic method which have input view model as generic input

Comment: I presume your `ViewModel`'s all inherit from a singular interface?

Comment: you should build an abstract viewmodel with the common fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all your `*ViewModel`-classes have a property named `UserTypes` of type `List<SelectListItem>` you can think about creating a base class for all `*ViewModel`s:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public List<SelectListItem> UserTypes { get; set; }
    // ... further code?
}
```

and inherit your view models from that class, for example:

```
public class RegisterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // implement specific behaviour
}
```

Then your method does not need to be generic, but can simply take a `ViewModelBase` as parameter:

```
private void SetUpUserType(ViewModelBase model)
{
    var usertypes = GetuserTypes();
    model.UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem> { };
    usertypes.ForEach(t => model.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Value }));
}
```

---

Just for completeness, you *can* make this method generic:

```
private void SetUpUserType<T>(T model) where T : ViewModelBase
{
    var usertypes = GetuserTypes();
    model.UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem> { };
    usertypes.ForEach(t => model.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Value }));
}
```

and use the constraint (`where T : ViewModelBase`) to make sure it's a type derived from `ViewModelBase` supporting that `UserTypes` property.

Comment: This is the correct solution and does not use generics but an inheritance based technique.  You could use generics but there is no reason to use them here as the only thing that matters is that the model inherits ViewModelBase.